# How to fill QCameraViewFinder with background color?

Tags: c++, qt, qcamera

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    m_QPushButton_calibration = new QPushButton("Calibrate", this);
    connect(m_QPushButton_calibration, SIGNAL (released()),this, SLOT (handleButton()));

    QList<QCameraInfo> l_QListQCameraInfo_available_cameras = QCameraInfo::availableCameras();

    m_QCameraViewfinder_viewfinder = new QCameraViewfinder(this);

    if (l_QListQCameraInfo_available_cameras.length() >= 2)
    {
        m_QCamera_required_camera = new QCamera (l_QListQCameraInfo_available_cameras[1]);
        m_QCamera_required_camera->setViewfinder(m_QCameraViewfinder_viewfinder);
        m_QCamera_required_camera->start ();
    }

    m_QWidget_central         = new QWidget;
    m_QGridLayout_main_screen = new QGridLayout;

    m_QWidget_central->setStyleSheet ("background-color: green");
    m_QWidget_central->setLayout (m_QGridLayout_main_screen);

    m_QPushButton_calibration->setStyleSheet ("background-color: pink");
    m_QGridLayout_main_screen->addWidget (m_QPushButton_calibration, 0, 0, 1, 1);

    m_QCameraViewfinder_viewfinder->setStyleSheet ("background-color: blue");
    m_QGridLayout_main_screen->addWidget (m_QCameraViewfinder_viewfinder, 1, 1, 2, 1);

    this->setCentralWidget (m_QWidget_central);

    m_QCameraViewfinder_viewfinder->show();
}
```

I have tried this: `m_QCameraViewfinder_viewfinder->setStyleSheet ("background-color: blue");`

Didn't help.

No camera attached as of now. How to fill QCameraViewFinder with background color?

Output is here:

[image]

Comment: Isn't your call to `m_QWidget_central->setStyleSheet ("background-color: green");` what's setting the bg to green?

Comment: I think view finder will display "video data" which has its own color. If no video data is available that defaults to black/green/whtever the underlying graphics subsystem produces. Best bet is to momentarily hide the viewfinder when it is not actively connected to a video source and just select the background color for whatever widget is BEHIND the viewfinder.